# Add path as git alias?

Tags: git, path, alias

Is there a way to add a folder path as a git alias, so that I don't have to retype the path every time when adding files?

I wanted to do something like:

```
fp = my/long/folder/path
```

So when I add files, I can simply `fp/file.html`

Answer (score 0):

on windows -- create a symbolic link

```
mklink /D C:\fp C:\my\long\folder\path
```

on unix \ os x -- if you make a fast switch to the directory using an alias in your ~/.bash_profile, you could switch to it rapidly and then just do git add filename.ext

```
alias fp="cd /my/long/folder/path"
```

Comment: I should have specified. I am on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't necessarily answer your question, but have you tried using [`git add -i`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging)?

Also, Git accepts wildcards when staging files, so this works:

```
git add *file.html
```

Or even this:

```
git add *file*
```